# How to notify FxOS app when the whole app crashed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, crash-reports, firefox-os, bugsense

Is there a way that we can be notified when the whole FxOS app **crashes**? Because I want to know what causes it to crash or errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API that will report what crashed your app. Why? Because you should've known better or have treated possible errors offhand.

What I would recommend is that you log your actions somehow. One of your options is using the Console API, which is something like this:

**Outputting a single object**

`var someObject = { str: "Some text", id: 5 };
console.log(someObject);`

This will output something like

`[09:27:13.475] ({str:"Some text", id:5})`

**Stack Traces**

The console object also supports outputting a stack trace, which will show you the call path taken to reach the point at which you've called `console.trace()` . It goes like this

```
foo();

function foo() {
  function bar() {
    console.trace();
  }
  bar();
}
```

And console will output something like this:

[image: Console.trace()]

**How to enable console logging on Firefox OS**

For more information on how to enable console logging on Firefox OS devices, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Debugging/On-device_console_logging)

**How to debug apps on Firefox OS**

For more information on how to debug apps on Firefox OS, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager)

Comment: "you should've known better" is the wrong response to crash monitoring. When thousands of users are running an app on dozesn of device and operating system combinations, things *will* go wrong and there should be ways to discover what happened.

Comment: I agree with you, there are several devices, different people use software in different ways. What I meant with that, is that the developer should be aware of dangerous code that could possibly break and threat it offhand (Either by catching that error and terminating the app himself, or logging as suggested). Sorry if it sounded aggressive.